# How to manually walk through the clang AST tree without consumer (C++ clang API)?

Tags: c++, api, clang

I have the following construction:

```cpp
AAA* classA = new AAA;
classA->functionA()->functionB()->functionC();
```

I have a "CXXMemberCallExpr (or FunctionDecl)" to "functionC()", which has the following structure:

```
|-CXXMemberCallExpr 0x11c2538 <line:117:5, col:49> 'class AAA *'
| `-MemberExpr 0x11c2514 <col:5, col:39> '<bound member function type>' ->functionC 0x11c0cf0
|   `-CXXMemberCallExpr 0x11c24f8 <col:5, col:36> 'class AAA *'
|     `-MemberExpr 0x11c24d4 <col:5, col:26> '<bound member function type>' ->functionB 0x11c0c60
|       `-CXXMemberCallExpr 0x11c24b8 <col:5, col:23> 'class AAA *'
|         `-MemberExpr 0x11c2494 <col:5, col:13> '<bound member function type>' ->functionA 0x11c0bd0
|           `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x11c2488 <col:5> 'class AAA *' <LValueToRValue>
|             `-DeclRefExpr 0x11c2470 <col:5> 'class AAA *' lvalue Var 0x11c2040 'classA' 'class AAA *'
```

Question: How to manually walk through the clang AST tree without consumer? And get "functionA" and "functionB", if I have only "CXXMemberCallExpr (or FunctionDecl)" on "functionC"?

Please help me if you can.